# Extract text from file over separate/separated lines in Python

Tags: python, text, extract

Hoping someone can help as I'm very new to Python and struggling a bit.

I need to take a text file's contents and extract elements of it into another file, capturing some lines but ignoring others.  As an example, this is a portion of the original file:

```
input1   
   name "Bob"   
   Always_active  
next_input  
input2   
   name "Alice"   
   Sometimes_active   
next_input  
input3   
   name "Ted"   
   Always_active   
next_input  
input4    
   name "Albert"   
   Never_active   
next_input  
input5   
   name "Sue"   
   Always_active   
next_input  
input6   
   name "David"   
   Never_active   
next_input  
input7   
   name "Building1"   
   Always_active   
next_input  
input8   
   name "Building2"   
   Always_active   
next_input  
input9   
   name "Building3"   
   Always_active   
next_input  
input10   
   name "Building4"     
   Always_active     
next_input
```

And this is what I'd like to be able to capture:

```
input1   
   name "Bob"   
input2   
   name "Alice"   
input3   
   name "Ted"   
input4   
   name "Albert"   
input5   
   name "Sue"   
input6   
   name "David"   
input7   
   name "Building1"   
input8    
   name "Building2"   
input9   
   name "Building3"   
input10   
   name "Building4"
```

So essentially I need to ignore some of the lines and capture the remainder.  How can I achieve this?

Comment: Thanks All, each answer was very helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can start with reading the file:

```
with open(r'C:\your_file_path\your_file_name.txt', 'r') as f:
    text = f.read().splitlines()
```

then you will have variable "text" which is a list and every element in this list is one of the lines from your text. Next you should check every line for your "condition"

```
new_text = []
for i in text:
    if i[:5] == 'input':
        new_text.append(i)
    elif i[:6] == 'name \"':
        new_text.append(i)
```

variable "new_text" is a list with elements-lines of text that you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

You should read the file line by line and filter the line you want to write them in a new file.

```
# First read file
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    file = f.readlines()

# Create new file
f2 = open(filename, 'a')

for line in file:
    if line not in ('Always_active', 'Never_active'): # Filter lines you don't want
        f2.write(line) # Write line
        f2.write('\n') # Break line

# Close file
f2.close()
```

Should work

Answer (score 0):

You could use *pandas* to read and edit the file.

Assuming you have the text saved in *temp_txt_file.txt* in the same folder as your python script.

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

data = pd.read_csv("./temp_txt_file.txt", header=None)
data_filtered = data.loc[data.loc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: x.find("name") == 0 or x.find("input") == 0)]
data_filtered.to_csv(path_or_buf='./filtered_data.txt', index=False, header=False, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```

You first load the data into a pandas.DataFrame. In the second line you **loc**ate all rows where your string begins with either *name* or *input* (this is done by .find(), which returns 0 if the string begins with the query)

*Note:* With **.apply(lambda x: function)** you apply a function to every row of the pandas.DataFrame with **x** containing the row as a string.

The code:

```
data.loc[:, 0].apply(lambda x: x.find("name") == 0 or x.find("input") == 0)
```

yields a series of "True / False" which you can consider as a mask for filtering out unwanted rows. You then apply (**loc**ate) this in the pandas.DataFrame and save it to a new file *filtered_data.txt" without any header and index of the pandas.DataFrame.

*Note:* qutoing=csv.QUOTE_NONE is needed to avoid unnecessary escape characters for "

*Advise:* if you can format the text file differently and using **.csv** file this would help a lot as it seems your data is somewhat a table. Then you could dig into **pandas** which is perfect for organizing data.